# Is there a way to configure where a new program window can appear?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I use the task bar on the top of my screen since windows XP because it fits better to my workflow. The problem is that sometimes new windows appear below the task bar and I can not directly move them unless I resize them first.

[image]

After I resize them just a little bit is like they say "oh! my controls are not reachable, let me fix it" and move some pixels to the bottom.

Is there a way to prevent this to happen? or to trigger a "resize me" event when a new window is open?

Comment: You found one of the reasons why MS forced people to have the taskbar at the bottom of the screen (the main one is to force you to lower your eyes in obidience...). When I have a window below the taskbar (which generally means that the app isn't well programmed btw), I hide the taskbar or move it. I never found any other solution. Note that on Linux you can move a window while pressing the alt key.

Comment: If you really want this to happen in an automated fashion, download the free scripting tool [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) and write a small script that resizes any window that draws part of itself in the pixel area occupied by the Taskbar.  Not the *easiest* solution but done correctly it will work quite nicely for any and all windows that are opened.

Comment: I have use AutoHotKey in the past. I never thought about use it for this! I will take a look, thanks @Twisty

Comment: @distante Be sure to post your own answer if you get such a script working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hit ***Windows key* + Up arrow** with the program selected, it will fullscreen the program to fit your screen.

**Left** and **right** arrow keys would snap it to the respective sides.

Let me know if that helps

Regarding prevention, I really cant say.  But if I come across something I will be sure to share.

Comment: I think this is the best workaround for this.